# How can I create a TLS connection without certificates in golang?

Tags: ssl, go

From the source:

```golang
// Listen creates a TLS listener accepting connections on the
// given network address using net.Listen.
// The configuration config must be non-nil and must include
// at least one certificate or else set GetCertificate.
func Listen(network, laddr string, config *Config) (net.Listener, error) {
    if config == nil || (len(config.Certificates) == 0 && config.GetCertificate == nil) {
        return nil, errors.New("tls: neither Certificates nor GetCertificate set in Config")
    }
    l, err := net.Listen(network, laddr)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return NewListener(l, config), nil
}
```

The problem is that the certificates cannot be nil:

```
// The configuration config must be non-nil and must include
// at least one certificate or else set GetCertificate.
```

How can I use a `tls` connection listening without certificates?
What I need is the `tls` **encryption** but **not the authentication**.

I tried making a tls.Config with an empty certificate like this:

```
&tls.Config{
            Certificates: []tls.Certificate{tls.Certificate{}},
}
```

But the connections failed with `tls: handshake failure`.
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLS without certificates would require support for cipher suites which don't use certificates.

Looking at the source code for `crypto/tls` one can find the supported cipher suites in [crypto/tls/cipher_suites.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/crypto/tls/cipher_suites.go#L77). One can see there that only cipher suites using either RSA or ECDSA authentication are supported, which means that you need to have a certificate with either RSA or ECC key.

To have support for TLS without certificates there need to be ciphers for PSK, SRP .. or similar authentication methods which don't require certificates or for the NULL  authentication (anonymous, i.e. no authentication). But these are not supported.

> What I need is the tls encryption but not the authentication.

In most cases such requirement is flawed in the first place. 
TLS without authentication would mean that an active and undetectable man in the middle attack is usually easily possible, which would essentially make all the encryption provided by TLS meaningless. TLS without authentication would only make sense if the client could securely (i.e.resistant against MITM attacks) authenticate the server after the TLS connection was established and before any application payload is transmitted.

Comment: I am indeed authenticating both points of the connections with a custom verify method. Does this mean that for example would be the same to just use some certificates and use `InsecureSkipVerify`? It will be encrypting the connection but not handling any authentication then right? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Netwave: Yes, you could use a self-signed certificate and simply not verify it in the client. But please note that your custom verify method must be resistant to man in the middle attacks. As long as the authentication is not finished you essentially have to treat the TLS channel like a plain channel where an attacker could not only sniff but also modify the traffic. Thus a simple password based authentication schema will not work.

Comment: Thanks, It is all I needed to know!!

Answer (score 0):

set InsecureSkipVerify to true at tls.Config

```
&tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}
```

and add that config to Transport

```
&http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: tlsConfig}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config

Comment: This keeps the `handshake failure` error, with an empty certificate and if no certificate added it just ask for it.